# Experience Editor returning lots of JS Errors when running in Docker

Tags: experience-editor, docker

I'm running Sitecore 8.2 Update 4, and am currently running Sitecore on my Sandbox using Docker. I've got 3 different containers: MongoDB, SQL Server, and then my Sitecore/IIS container. I've actually got my website up and running, with 1 caveat. Whenever I try to go to Experience Editor, I get a BUNCH of Require.js errors, making it impossible for the Experience Editor to work. Here's some of the errors:

```
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:449 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/preview.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:466 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/delete.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:475 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/document_header.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:481 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/view_locked_documents.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:481 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/arrow_fork.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:496 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/markup.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:487 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/publish.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:532 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/layout_details.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:529 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/windows.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:532 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/reset_layout.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:568 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/32x32/navigate_right.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:576 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/camera.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:600 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/reset_fields.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:612 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/compare_versions.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:666 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ContentTesting/Assets/tests/16x16/suggested_test.png 500 (Internal Server Error)
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:666 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ContentTesting/Assets/tests/16x16/active_test.png 500 (Internal Server Error)
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:666 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ContentTesting/Assets/tests/16x16/historical_test.png 500 (Internal Server Error)
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:750 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/target.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:750 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/tags.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:750 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/pencil.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b818C35A2-2E91-4ED2-BD46-147F9EEDC607%7d%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_site%3DHopeRestored&lang=en&pageSite=HopeRestored&version=1:756 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/inbox_into.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
require.js:1895 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceExplorer/Commands/ExplorerMode.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
req.load @ require.js:1895
(More Stack trace in here)
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: /sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceExplorer/Commands/ExplorerMode.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:1895 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ContentTesting/ShowActiveTestsCommand.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
req.load @ require.js:1895
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: /sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ContentTesting/ShowActiveTestsCommand.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:1895 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ContentTesting/ShowHistoricalTestsCommand.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
req.load @ require.js:1895
load @ require.js:1639
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: /sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ContentTesting/ShowHistoricalTestsCommand.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:1895 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Commands/EnableEditing.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
req.load @ require.js:1895
load @ require.js:1639
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: /sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Commands/EnableEditing.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:1895 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Commands/EnableFieldsValidation.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
req.load @ require.js:1895
load @ require.js:1639
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: /sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Commands/EnableFieldsValidation.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:1895 GET http://sandbox.hoperestored.com:8000/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Commands/ShowNavigationBar.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
req.load @ require.js:1895
load @ require.js:1639
```

The files all seem to exist at the right place, and so I know that the problem is not with the file location. However, I can't seem to figure out why the host machine can't get access to those files. If I try to access the individual files from a browser, those resources load fine.

Where do I start in figuring out what the problem is?

Thanks!

**Update:**
Here's my dockerfile that I am using to create my sitecore website.

```
# More information about the aspnet base container;
# https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2-windowsservercore

# Create the website directory which hold the sitecore website files.
RUN mkdir C:\website

# DNS Resolver Cache Service
RUN set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters' \
    -Name ServerPriorityTimeLimit -Value 0 -Type DWord

# Configure IIS
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
    Import-module IISAdministration; \
    New-IISSite -Name "Sitecore" -PhysicalPath C:\website -BindingInformation "*:8000:"

# Make the exposed port is the same as the -BindingInformation option
# given in the powershell command.
EXPOSE 8000
```

And here's my Docker-compose.yml file that I am using to put everything together:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: istern/windows-mongo
  mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express:latest
    mem_limit: 2g
    expose:
    - "1433"
    environment:
    - sa_password=MyPassword
    - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    - attach_dbs="[{'dbName':'Sitecore_Analytics','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Analytics.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Analytics.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Core','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Core.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Core.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Master','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Master.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Master.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Sessions','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Sessions.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Sessions.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Web','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Web.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Web.ldf']}]" 
    volumes:
    - ./sitecore/Databases:C:/databases/
  web:
    build: ./web 
    mem_limit: 6g    
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
    - ./sitecore/Website:C:/website/
    - ./sitecore/Data:C:/website-data/
    depends_on:
    - mssql
    - mongodb
    links:
    - mssql
    - mongodb
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Thanks for any insight that you might be able to share!

Comment: I'm also running in Docker and don't see any problems with the experience editor. What do you see in the Sitecore logs on the requests that failed with HTTP 500? I'm running in "CMS only" mode (ie. disabled xdb and analytics in config), could be a difference too. Are you running latest microsoft/aspnet:4.6, they just release a new version? Could you also post your Docker file?

Comment: If your are not running latest version of microsoft/aspnet, look into this issue for details and workarounds for default app pool permissions: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/issues/33

Comment: @pbering I am not seeing any errors in Sitecore logs, which is part of what is causing my frustration. I was running the latest version of microsoft/aspnet, so I might try going back to something different. I will update my original post with my docker file for Sitecore, as well as my docker-compose file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up rebuilding my docker image, this time not using the `volumes` capability on the `docker-compose.yml` file. So my file now looks like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: istern/windows-mongo
  mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express:latest
    mem_limit: 2g
    expose:
    - "1433"
    environment:
    - sa_password=myPassword
    - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    - attach_dbs="[{'dbName':'Sitecore_Analytics','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Analytics.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Analytics.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Core','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Core.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Core.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Master','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Master.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Master.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Sessions','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Sessions.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Sessions.ldf']},{'dbName':'Sitecore_Web','dbFiles':['C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Web.mdf','C:\\databases\\Sitecore.Web.ldf']}]" 
    volumes:
    - ./sitecore/Databases:C:/databases/
  web:
    image: myCompany/Sitecore82u4
    mem_limit: 6g    
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
    - mssql
    - mongodb
    links:
    - mssql
    - mongodb
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

My Sitecore docker image loads a LOT faster, and everything seems to be working now. So it seems as if the version of Docker for Windows that I'm using `(17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87)` doesn't handle the volumes very well.

I hope that helps others!

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the speed of your disk's. When you build your own image, it's default stored on your C: drive and when you mount volumes, the mount point is where your compose/docker file are. So if that disk is slower than your C: drive that would be why you are experiencing it to be faster. Normally it's the other way around, volumes are faster. Anyways good that it works for you now.